# How do I stop a Listening server in Go

Tags: sockets, networking, go, listen

I've been trying to find a way to stop a listening server in Go gracefully.  Because `listen.Accept` blocks it is necessary to close the listening socket to signal the end, but I can't tell that error apart from any other errors as the relevant error isn't exported.

Can I do better than this? See `FIXME` in the code below in `serve()`

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"
    "time"
)

// Echo server struct
type EchoServer struct {
    listen net.Listener
    done   chan bool
}

// Respond to incoming connection
//
// Write the address connected to then echo
func (es *EchoServer) respond(remote *net.TCPConn) {
    defer remote.Close()
    _, err := io.Copy(remote, remote)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error: %s", err)
    }
}

// Listen for incoming connections
func (es *EchoServer) serve() {
    for {
        conn, err := es.listen.Accept()
        // FIXME I'd like to detect "use of closed network connection" here
        // FIXME but it isn't exported from net
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Accept failed: %v", err)
            break
        }
        go es.respond(conn.(*net.TCPConn))
    }
    es.done <- true
}

// Stop the server by closing the listening listen
func (es *EchoServer) stop() {
    es.listen.Close()
    <-es.done
}

// Make a new echo server
func NewEchoServer(address string) *EchoServer {
    listen, err := net.Listen("tcp", address)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to open listening socket: %s", err)
    }
    es := &EchoServer{
        listen: listen,
        done:   make(chan bool),
    }
    go es.serve()
    return es
}

// Main
func main() {
    log.Println("Starting echo server")
    es := NewEchoServer("127.0.0.1:18081")
    // Run the server for 1 second
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    // Close the server
    log.Println("Stopping echo server")
    es.stop()
}
```

This prints

```
2012/11/16 12:53:35 Starting echo server
2012/11/16 12:53:36 Stopping echo server
2012/11/16 12:53:36 Accept failed: accept tcp 127.0.0.1:18081: use of closed network connection
```

I'd like to hide the `Accept failed` message, but obviously I don't want to mask other errors `Accept` can report.  I could of course look in the error test for `use of closed network connection` but that would be really ugly.  I could set a flag saying I'm about to close and ignore errors if that was set I suppose - Is there a better way?

Comment: I believe it is a good explanation. https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/correct-shutdown-of-net-listener/8705

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check some "is it time to stop" flag in your loop right after the `accept()` call, then flip it from your `main`, then *connect* to your listening port to get server socket "un-stuck". This is very similar to the old ["self-pipe trick"](http://cr.yp.to/docs/selfpipe.html).

Comment: That is a neat idea!  There is a race condition with real connections coming in though which you'd need to work around.

Comment: Yes, true. You can try an inverse of that - always have that single internal connection from the start and use it as a control channel.

Comment: Great and simple!

Answer (score 18):

I would handle this by using es.done to send a signal before it closes the connection.  In addition to the following code you'd need to create es.done with make(chan bool, 1) so that we can put a single value in it without blocking.

```
// Listen for incoming connections
func (es *EchoServer) serve() {
  for {
    conn, err := es.listen.Accept()
    if err != nil {
      select {
      case <-es.done:
        // If we called stop() then there will be a value in es.done, so
        // we'll get here and we can exit without showing the error.
      default:
        log.Printf("Accept failed: %v", err)
      }
      return
    }
    go es.respond(conn.(*net.TCPConn))
  }
}

// Stop the server by closing the listening listen
func (es *EchoServer) stop() {
  es.done <- true   // We can advance past this because we gave it buffer of 1
  es.listen.Close() // Now it the Accept will have an error above
}
```

Comment: Hmm, nice idea.  I think a `bool` would do just as well as using the channel though which is pretty much the solution I came up with. You still need the channel though to synchronise the `stop` with `serve` so you know when it has stopped.

Comment: Don't bother buffering the channel or sending a message down the channel.  Just close it.

Answer (score 2):

Something among these lines might work in this case, I hope:

```
// Listen for incoming connections
func (es *EchoServer) serve() {
        for {
                conn, err := es.listen.Accept()
                if err != nil {
                    if x, ok := err.(*net.OpError); ok && x.Op == "accept" { // We're done
                            log.Print("Stoping")
                            break
                    }

                    log.Printf("Accept failed: %v", err)
                    continue
                }
                go es.respond(conn.(*net.TCPConn))
        }
        es.done <- true
}
```

Comment: A good idea thanks!  I'm not sure it would tell apart an official stop from `Syscall.Accept()` returning an error (a recent example I've seen is the process running out of sockets) would it?

Comment: Dunno, I would have to try/experiment with it.

Comment: Great example, but shouldn't the `x.Op` be compared to `close`, e.g. `&& x.Op == "close"` If we stop the listener by using `listener.Close()`, it seems to put close inside the error operation. https://godoc.org/net#TCPListener.Close

Answer (score -7):

Here's a simple way that's good enough for local development.

http://www.sergiotapia.me/how-to-stop-your-go-http-server/

---

```
package main

import (  
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "github.com/bmizerany/pat"
)

var mux = pat.New()

func main() {  
    mux.Get("/kill", http.HandlerFunc(kill))
    http.Handle("/", mux)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func kill(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {  
    os.Exit(0)
}
```

Comment: Exiting the entire process is not a valid way to close a server!