# What is an idiomatic method of listening for events in Go?

Tags: events, concurrency, go, idioms, event-loop

A few months ago I was thinking how to implement a **closable** event loop in Go, for an RPC library. I managed to facilitate closing the server like so:

```
type Server struct {
    listener net.Listener
    closeChan chan bool
    routines sync.WaitGroup
}

func (s *Server) Serve() {
    s.routines.Add(1)
    defer s.routines.Done()
    defer s.listener.Close()

    for {
        select {
            case <-s.closeChan:
                // close server etc.
            default:
                s.listener.SetDeadline(time.Now().Add(2 * time.Second))
                conn, _ := s.listener.Accept()
                // handle conn routine
        }
    }
}

func (s *Server) Close() {
    s.closeChan <- true // signal to close serve routine
    s.routines.Wait()
}
```

The problem that I've found with this implementation is it involves a timeout, which means minimum close time is 2 seconds more than it could be. Is there a more idiomatic method of creating an event loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that event loops in Go need to be loops.

It would seem simpler to handle closing and connections in separate goroutines:

```
go func() {
    <-s.closeChan
    // close server, release resources, etc.
    s.listener.Close()
}()
for {
    conn, err := s.listener.Accept()
    if err != nil {
         // log, return
    }
    // handle conn routine
}
```

Note that you might also close the listener directly in your Close function without using a channel. What I have done here is used the error return value of Listener.Accept to facilitate inter-routine communication.

If at some point of the closing and connection handling implementations you need to protect some resources you're closing while you're answering, you may use [a Mutex](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex). But it's generally possible to avoid that.

Comment: Listeners are thread safe. Closing from another goroutine will immediately force the Accept() to return with an error. However, you can't ignore the error or you will end up with an endless loop.

Comment: @StephenWeinberg I'm confused - how does this exit the Serve function?

Comment: @liamzebedee when the listener is closed, the Accept function returns an error. That's why I suggest you return if you have such an error.

Comment: Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13417095/how-do-i-stop-a-listening-server-in-go