# How to know when the net.Listener was properly closed?

Tags: networking, go

I have the following code:

```
server := &http.Server{Addr: addr, Handler: r}

l, err := net.Listen("tcp", addr)
if err != nil {
    logging.Error("Failed opening socket: %s", err)
}

if err := server.Serve(l); err != nil {
    // error handling
}
```

When `l.Close()` is called, `server.Serve(l)` will exit with an error. I would like to know whether this is truly an error or just the result of someone calling `l.Close()` (which is non error for me).

Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: Check the error? I'm not sure you can rely on `close()` being distinguishable from network card failure though, and I can't off the top of my head see any other reasons for `Serve()` to fail.

Comment: This question is related to what you want to know [how do you stop a listening server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13417095/how-do-i-stop-a-listening-server-in-go)

Answer (score 1):

Some hack-ish way about TCP socket:

```
read_len, err := conn.Read(request)

if err != nil {

  if err.Error() == "use of closed network connection" { 
    // Do something when socket closed
    break
  }
```

Try `if err.Error() == "use of closed network connection"` under `if err := server.Serve(l); err != nil {`, or in your TCP handler function.

Comment: Thought about this too, but was looking for something more robust. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With interfaces that implement `io.ReadWriteCloser` you typically get back an `io.EOF` and `io.ErrUnexpectedEOF` error. `net.Listener` implements `io.Closer`, so I would expect it to also return this error, but it unfortunately does not follow this convention. Instead, it returns a privately declared [errClosing in net.go](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/net.go#L341).

Errors returned by `net.Listener` are wrapped in `net.OpError`. This struct has some additional information that may be helpful - specifically "Op" and "Err". "Op" tells you where the error occurred. When you execute `Close() error` you get "accept" back. The documentation says you can also get "read" and "write" back.

To get `net.OpError`, you can do this:

```
err := server.Serve(l)
if opErr, ok := err.(*net.OpError); ok {
    // opErr.Op, opErr.Err, ...
}
```

Or like this (assuming that `net.Listener` always returns a `net.OpError`):

```
err := server.Serve(l).(*net.OpError)
```

net.OptError.Err returns the original error, which would be helpful *if* the error was exported. Either way I don't recommend checking the string as that could break in future versions. It's better to compare the error directly to the exported error, which you don't have.

`net.OptError` also has a `Temporary() bool` function declared. The `net/http` package [uses this](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/server.go#L1544) to re-establish the connection on a increasing interval. So in the case of `net/http` I would assume that any error that returns would be a result of calling `Close() error`. Otherwise `Temporary() bool` would return true, which `net/http` catches for you.

Comment: Did you try running the code sample? When I try it, `server.Serve(l)` doesn't return io.EOF when you close the connection (by calling `l.Close()`).

Comment: @arikfr Sorry, I did not realize that net.Listener did not follow the same convention as net.Conn. Closing a listening connection isn't very common. Did a bit more digging, updated answer.